# VSCode Editor Gutter Color Change (SynthWave 84 theme)

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

I wanna change editor gutter's (line number column) color in VSCode, I turned on the neon from synthwave 84 theme and changed the editor theme to material ocean. This it what it looks like:

[image: This it what it looks like]

Everything is fine expect the gutter (line number column) color which is always purple. How can I merge it with editor color?

Comment: find the theme name of these colors and customize them, that can be done by theme

Comment: I know i have to do that but i don't know the way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

[solution screenshot that prove - it works!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsWey.png)

FULL INSTRUCTION & ATTACHMENTS:
https://github.com/vadym4che/synthwave-black-neon/blob/main/synthwave-vadym4che.zip
[FULL INSTRUCTION & ATTACHMENTS](https://github.com/vadym4che/synthwave-black-neon/blob/main/synthwave-vadym4che.zip)

FIX SUBTLE BACKGROUND PLOBLEM:

---

|1| find file called "neondreams.js" that is placing at this path (or something aroun this):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\code\electron-sandbox\workbench\neondreams.js

|2| replace it by file that is attached in folder ".vscode--extensions--robbowen.synthwave--vscode-0.1.15"

OR fix by your own hands -> near 98th line of code that affecting your GUTTER color

```
/* Add the subtle gradient to the editor background */
.monaco-editor {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000000 75%, #000000);
  background-size: auto 100vh;
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

---

ALSO YOU CAN USE MY TOTAL BLACK NEON GLOWED THEME .json

for porpose of that replace file(s) at path:

~.vscode\extensions\robbowen.synthwave-vscode-0.1.15\

with files attached in folder "AppData--Local--Programs--Microsoft VS Code--resources--app--out--vscode--electron-sandbox--workbench"

---

i want to stay thankful for post that get by far closer to real working solution of this problem:
https://github.com/robb0wen/synthwave-vscode/issues/199